# How to write an expression that creates a pandas series from a larger pandas dataset?

Tags: pandas, series

I am being asked to "write an expression that returns a pandas Series with just the names in the name column." Below is the code which returns a large pandas dataset with three columns: 'name', 'sex', 'births'. Even after studying pandas series documentation, I am still at a loss on how to create such an expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
names2000 = pd.read_csv('/Users/dk/desktop/yob2000.txt',names=
['name','sex','births'])
names2000
```

Should my code look something like this?:

```
s = pd.Series(names2000, index = 'name')
```

Comment: was is names2000 ?

Comment: 'names2000' is the name that my teacher gave to the pandas dataframe which lists popular baby names from the year 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression should be:

```
names2000['name']
```

This will return the names column from the names2000 dataframe as a pd.Series.

You can use `type` to verify.

```
type(names2000['names'])
```

Comment: thank you! Why didn't I have to pass in more arguments as described in the pandas series documentation? i.e.: pandas.Series(data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False, fastpath=False) . Also, why didn't I even have to append the ".Series" to "names2000"?

Comment: Danny, Pandas when selecting a single column from a dataframe will make the return a pd.Series using the single bracket notation. Now, if you want to return a dataframe with a single column then you can use 'names2000[['name']].

Comment: @Danny if this answer helped you, would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)